# Symfony 2 & Assetic - Import font from google font api

Tags: css, symfony, fonts, twig, assetic

I'm currently working on a Symfony 2 web app, but I have a problem with  Assetic (I think) when I import a font from Google font...

When I work with dev env in local, I see the request sent to Google to retrieve the font, but when I publish my work online with prod env, no request is sent and of course the font is not loaded properly...

Here is my assetic configuration (config.yml) :

```
assetic:
debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
use_controller: false
bundles:        ['MyBundle']
filters:
    cssrewrite: ~
assets:
    bootstrap_js:
        inputs:
            - %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twitter/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js
    bootstrap_css:
        inputs:
            - %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twitter/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css
            - %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twitter/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css
        filters: [cssrewrite]
    bootstrap_glyphicons_ttf:
        inputs:
            - %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twitter/bootstrap/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
        output: "fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf"
    bootstrap_glyphicons_eot:
        inputs:
            - %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twitter/bootstrap/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
        output: "fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot"
    bootstrap_glyphicons_svg:
        inputs:
            - %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twitter/bootstrap/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg
        output: "fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg"
    bootstrap_glyphicons_woff:
        inputs:
            - %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twitter/bootstrap/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
        output: "fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff"
    jquery:
        inputs:
            - %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/components/jquery/jquery.js
            - %kernel.root_dir%/../web/js/jquery.mmenu.min.js
            - %kernel.root_dir%/../web/js/jquery-ui.min.js
    public_js:
        inputs:
            - %kernel.root_dir%/../web/js/momentjs.min.js
            - %kernel.root_dir%/../web/js/fullcalendar2.min.js
            - %kernel.root_dir%/../web/js/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.min.js
            - %kernel.root_dir%/../web/js/menu.js
    style_css:
        inputs:
            - %kernel.root_dir%/../web/css/style.css
            - %kernel.root_dir%/../web/css/jquery.mmenu.css
            - %kernel.root_dir%/../web/css/jquery.mmenu.positioning.css
            - %kernel.root_dir%/../web/js/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.css
            - %kernel.root_dir%/../web/js/owl-carousel/owl.theme.css
    homepage_css:
        inputs:
            - %kernel.root_dir%/../web/css/homepage.css
    shop_css:
        inputs:
            - %kernel.root_dir%/../web/css/shop.css
    championship_css:
        inputs:
            - %kernel.root_dir%/../web/css/championship.css
    admin_css:
        inputs:
            - %kernel.root_dir%/../web/css/admin.css
    admin_js:
        inputs:
            - %kernel.root_dir%/../web/js/admin.js
    paypal_js:
        inputs:
            - %kernel.root_dir%/../web/js/paypal-button.min.js
```

In order to work without having to install assets all the time, I have in my config_dev.yml :

```
assetic:
    use_controller: true
```

In `style.css`, I import a font with :
`@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo:300,400,500,700,400italic,500italic,700italic,300italic);`

And in the header of my TWIG templates (e.g. shop page) :

```
{% stylesheets '@bootstrap_css' '@style_css' '@shop_css'%}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="{{ asset_url }}"/>
{% endstylesheets %}
```

When I put my work online, I run `php app/console assetic:dump` and everything is working well, no warning, no errors, my changes are loaded...  But the font is not loaded ! When I inspect the source code, the asset file is here and it contains the @import line I need... But the font is not loaded, and in Networks tab in Chrome dev tools, there is no request sent to Google to retrieve the font.

If I don't find a solution I will put the font in my files, but I would prefer the @import method !
I can't see what is going wrong, I'm stuck, please help, thx !

Comment: I have the same problem here. I know it won't help, but indeed, if someone has any clue or solution to fix this issue, you're welcome.

Answer (score 3):

> @import rules must precede all other rules (except the @charset rule, if present).

Since Assetic merges all the CSS files in the block into one file, your @import rule becomes preceded by all the rules in @bootstrap_css.

Just move your @import rules to another file and place it in first position in the stylesheets block.

Answer (score 1):

I simply included the `link` tag in the HTML head, but would have preferred the `@import` method

Comment: Same issue + fix here.  Would love to find out the cause.

Comment: I think Daniels answer just about sums it up.